# Determinant of parametric function and $0!1!2!...n!$

Tags: matrices, determinant, factorial, closed-form

As answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633724/prove-ex-e2x-enx-is-linear-independent-on-the-vector-space-of-ma/634948#634948), I trued to calculate the wronskian of:

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
e^x & e^{2x} & ... & e^{nx}\\
e^x & 2e^{2x} & ...& ne^{nx} \\
e^x & 4e^{2x} &... & n^2e^{nx}\\
...&...&...&...\\
e^x&2^{n-1}e^{2x} & ... & n^{n-1}e^{nx}\end{array} \right|
$$
What led to:
$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
1 & 2 & ...& n \\
1 & 4 &... & n^2\\
...&...&...&...\\
1 &2^{n-1} & ... & n^{n-1}\end{array} \right|$$
So I tried to calculate it for small values of n. The results were:

- $n=1\to1=0!$
- $n=2\to1=0!1!$
- $n=3\to2=0!1!2!$
- $n=4\to12=0!1!2!3!$
- $n=5\to288=0!1!2!3!4!$

So I have two questions:

1. Is it true for the general case?, I mean:
   $$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
   1 & 2 & ...& n \\
   1 & 4 &... & n^2\\
   ...&...&...&...\\
   1 &2^{n-1} & ... & n^{n-1}\end{array} \right|=0!*1!*2!*...*(n-1)!$$
2. Is there some more closed form for this expression?

What I tried is
$$0!1!2!...n!=(1)*(1*2)*(1*2*3)*...(1*2*3*...*n)=1^n*2^{n-1}*3^{n-2}*...*(n-1)^2*n$$
But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix $M$ is a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). (Or at least the transpose of one with respect to the definition on wikipedia). You immediately obtain

$$\det(M)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (\alpha_j-\alpha_i),$$ where $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)=(1,2,\ldots,n)$, and your formula follows.

By the way, these are superfactorials and more information can be found at [OEIS A000178](http://oeis.org/A000178).