# Linear dependence and sequence of funcions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm making my homework of Linear Algebra, so there is a exercise kind of weird, it's probably false:

Let's $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions such that $f_n(x) = e^{xn}$, show that the set $f_n$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}.$

But the statement is not true (I guess), take $a_1= e$, $a_2= -1$ and $a_n=0, \forall n \geq2$. Then

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ie^{xi}=0$, for $x=1$... but there is $a_i \neq 0. $

Comment: $\mathrm e \mathrm e^x - \mathrm e^{2x} = \mathrm e^{x + 1} - \mathrm e^{2x} \neq 0$.

Comment: ok, but if you take $x=1$ you have that...

Comment: Yes, but $0$ is here the zero function $f \equiv 0$, and you would need to have it for $every\ x$.

Comment: ok, I got it, so the assumption it is true?

Comment: You need to check the linear independence for any arbitrary finite subset of that sequence.

Comment: Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633724/prove-ex-e2x-enx-is-linear-independent-on-the-vector-space-of-ma

Answer (score 1):

The linear dependence relation must hold for all $x$ in the domain. If you establish it for a single point, you are in fact establishing the linear dependence of a set of reals (namely $e^{nx_0}$ with $x_0=1$), not of functions. And reals are *always* linearly dependent.